# Why `lynx --dump` is not working

Tags: lynx

When I do

```
lynx --dump http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt
```

It outputs the content on this web page but when I do

```
lynx --dump https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf
```

It dumps something else than what is presented in the browser.

**Why the first command is working but the second command is not working and how do I make it work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lynx --dump 'https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf'
```

You need to quote the URL in this case since it contains `;`.  The semicolons delimit commands in the shell and will not be part of the URL if the URL is not properly quoted.

In fact, the bits in-between the semi colons will be interpreted as commands, which means that you now have shell variables called `a` and `f`:

```
$ echo "$a"
blob_plain

$ echo "$f"
manuf
```

The other reason that the URL needs to be quoted is that it contains a shell filename globbing character: `?`.